# Why does theme's reset CSS have higher precedence of plugin's CSS?

Tags: plugin-development, css, theme-twenty-twenty-one

In the [style.css](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentytwentyone/1.1/style.css#L1028) of the theme Twenty Twenty-One, there is a piece of reset CSS:

```
/**
 * Reset specific elements to make them easier to style in other contexts.
 */
html, body, p, ol, ul, li, dl, dt, dd, blockquote, figure, fieldset, form, legend, textarea, pre, iframe, hr, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Why does it have higher precedence than the CSS in my custom plugin? The result is that I have to add `!important` to override this.

Here is the code in my plugin:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 482px) {
  p {
    margin-top: 30px !important;
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
    /* margin-bottom: var(--global--spacing-vertical); */
  }
}
```

I target the general `p`, not a specific class.

Comment: I think this is not really WP related but a general CSS question. The idea of "reset" is very common in CSS, usually to remove default browser styles - I'm sure if you search for the topic online you'll find helpful resources. As for why this has precedence over your code would require to know what your CSS rules are. If its just `ul` and the theme stylesheet is enqueued later, then that explains it.

Comment: @kero do you know how to check if the stylesheet is enqueued later? In my case this is `p`

Comment: Does your plugins CSS get printed _before_ the themes? The order CSS is loaded in the HTML file matters, specificity in CSS isn't just how specific your rule is, or where in the file it happens, the order it is loaded in matters too. Take a look at CSS specificity. There's also no code in your question to debug or reproduce the problem. Enqueued styles are not sandboxed, they work the same for themes and plugins, WP cannot distinguish between the two

Comment: Specificity takes precedence in CSS. The reset applies to general `p`, but if your CSS specifies `.my-stuff p`, your rule will override the reset.

Comment: I can’t think of any reason a plugin should be setting styles for just `p`.

Comment: @vancoder I want to target a general `p`

Comment: But `p` everywhere? So even in wp-admin? No? Then there is at least one `body` class you can add. `p` only in post content? Bam, even another parent selector you can use.

Comment: @kero too much magic I cannot handle...

Comment: @Ooker Then you are in a similar position as your "Wanderer über dem Nebelmeer": While you might visualize your goal, the actual implementation is just a sea of fog to you right now. This is the perfect opportunity to deepen your knowledge in CSS and clear out that fog one step at a time.

Comment: Ahh the old Wanderer über dem Nebelmeer argument. Classic.

Comment: @vancoder it's even named as a kind of argument???